# Бесплатная среда для разработки

Tags: c++

С помощью каких средств разрабатывается такой GUI как например в FireFox, Chome итд? Какие есть бесплатные IDE для разработки коммерческого софта с похожим интерфейсом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от целевой платформы. Если это Windows, то IDE - Visual Studio Express. Если это Mac OS, то IDE - XCODE. Chrome сделан на WTL, какая именно IDE использовалась, сказать трудно. Но практически наверняка та же Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Qt Creator не пойдет? Есть и конструктор форм и нормальный редактор.

Comment: Qt для коммерческих целей надо покупать, это не совсем бесплатная ide

Answer (score 1):

можете скачать Visual C++ Express Editon

Comment: А как там с разработкой интерфейса

Comment: С разработкой интерфейса там все отлично.